# Next.js SWC - ESLint is unable to resolve path to module with aliases

Tags: javascript, next.js, babeljs, eslint, swc-compiler

I'm migrating my Next.js project from Babel compiler to Next.js SWC-powered compiler - https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler

After the necessary changes the app itself works fine, however inside the app there are imports that were powered by Babel's Module Resolver plugin - https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver

The `.babelrc` config itself is defining these aliases like this -

```json
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./"],
        "alias": {
          "~": "./src",
          "~~": "./"
        }
      }
    ],
```

but ESLint cannot resolve the imports defined either with `~` or `~~` e.g. -

```
Unable to resolve path to module '~/services/my-service'. eslintimport/no-unresolved
```

Inside `.eslintrc` there's `import/resolver` settings (Babel import resolver removed - https://github.com/tleunen/eslint-import-resolver-babel-module) e.g. -

```json
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      'node': {
      // 'babel-module': {
      //   'extensions': ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
      // },
        'extensions': ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
      }
    }
  }
```

Not sure what is missing in this setup. How does SWC knows the correct aliases `~` or `~~` and what should be done to make ESLint happy again?

Comment: Can you post your `.eslintrc` and `tsconfig.json`? Also, what's your Next.js version?

Comment: solved by installing https://github.com/import-js/eslint-import-resolver-typescript instead of https://github.com/tleunen/eslint-import-resolver-babel-module